# Shading issues with custom normals on cell fractured object

Tags: normals, cell-fracture

Why is the shading doing this? I've followed some steps on here for how to get a seamless cell fracture but this is the result im getting.

- Custom normals on original mesh before fracture
- Data transfer modifier on a fractured object with the following settings

  - ```
    Face Corner Data
    ```
  - ```
    CustomNormals
    ```
  - ```
    Nearest Corner of nearest face
    ```

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, shouldn't there be many fragments? I can see only one in the outliner? And when you have many all of the fragments need the *Data Transfer* modifier. And which steps have you followed? A link to the question(s) would help the readers here. Also, how have you added the Custom Normals?

Comment: Another related question that you've asked: [Adding Custom normals to an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241147/adding-custom-normals-to-an-object)